# HTML Webpage working correct when runned locally, throws Uncaught TypeError when embedded into a Google Earth Project

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth

I am working on a class project where I am creating a Google Earth Project and customizing the information box for each location in the project. (Project link here: https://earth.google.com/earth/d/1mJl_DRSTJqYvKIzLOUnTrEeUiMIbJh6H?usp=sharing)

On the information boxes, I have a button to display more content, the code for it is as follows: (Code for page 2 titled Cenacle in the project)

```
<script>
   let state = "hidden";
   function historicFactsFunc() {
     if (state === "hidden") {
       jQuery("#historicFacts")[0].innerHTML = "<p>Scholars don't think this is the correct site</p>";
       state = "visible";
     } else {
       jQuery("#historicFacts")[0].innerHTML = "";
       state = "hidden";
     }
   };
 </script>

 <div class="place">
    <h3>About the Cenacle</h3>
    <p class="placetxt">Cenacle, also ..text..</p>
    <button onclick="historicFactsFunc()">Is it historically accurate?</button>
    <div id="historicFacts"></div>     
 </div>
```

When I test this as a stand alone website locally, it works fine. When I embed in the Google Earth project's information box as HTML it throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: historicFactsFunc is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (about:srcdoc:1:1)` when I click the button. Why is this happening, and how can I make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your button?  Be aware that Google Earth parses through all the links in a balloon when rendering it, to determine which are KML action links that Earth should handle (pointing to another placemark or balloon), and which are web links that should be sent to the browser.  When you have a link with a built in function like that, it may not be recognized as a link correctly.  Also, when I inspect a balloon in your project right now, it's not showing the onclick function... did you remove it?  If not, maybe it's getting scrubbed out by the balloon renderer?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ChristiaanAdams No, I did not remove the onclick, it is there but somehow is not recognizing it. Maybe it did get scrubbed out by the balloon renderer. Is there any way to get around it or another way to implement a button into the project?

Comment: Yes, must be getting scrubbed somehow, possibly something to do with JS security. There are plenty of ways to implement a link or button with HTML+JS that will work in balloons in Earth 9 for web.  Again, what are you trying to do with the button? Do you want it to open an external web page?  Do you want it to change the content in the balloon?  Do you want it to fly to the location or pop the balloon of another placemark?

Comment: I was trying to update the inner HTML of another element using the button and finally figured it out. I moved the script from the body of the HTML to the head and it started to work. Also, here is a helpful video on implementing video and audio to Google Earth which I used to figure out the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXgFjin1Vl8

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out.  Yes, keeping scripts in the Head sounds safer.